# Apk not build of cordova project

Tags: android, cordova

Apk not build.

rampratap@ram-pratap:/opt/lampp/htdocs/cordova/newapp$ cordova requirements
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:

> Java JDK: installed 1.8.0 Android SDK: installed true Android target:
>   installed Google Inc.:Google APIs:24,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23,Google
>   Inc.:Google APIs:22,Google Inc.:Google APIs:21,Google Inc.:Google
>   APIs:19,Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19,Google
>   Inc.:Google APIs:18,Google Inc.:Google APIs:17,Google Inc.:Google
>   APIs:16,Google Inc.:Google
>   APIs:15,android-28,android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-20,android-19,android-18,android-17,android-16,android-15,android-14,android-13,android-12,android-11,android-10,android-9,android-8,android-7
>
> Gradle: installed /usr/lib/gradle-3.4.1/bin/gradle

Requirements check results for browser:

> rampratap@ram-pratap:/opt/lampp/htdocs/cordova/newapp$ sudo cordova
>   build android [sudo] password for rampratap:
>
> Android Studio project detected

Answer (score 0):

Please try `cordova requirements`to see what is missing, then is the rest to solve that.